# Sakai2.9.1 deployment issue in eclipse,Some maven issue

Tags: maven, sakai

```
[ERROR] The project org.sakaiproject:master:2.9.1 (C:\Users\juhi_juneja\Desktop\sakai-  src-2.9.1\sakai-src-2.9.1\master\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-  parent:pom:7
from/to sakai-maven (http://source.sakaiproject.org/maven2): 
connection timed out  
to http://source.sakaiproject.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom 
and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

Comment: Try visiting http://source.sakaiproject.org/maven2 on that machine, and when it works, try again.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when you are using an older version of maven. The first thing you should do is upgrade to the latest version of maven 3.
If that doesn't work then the issue is typically that you modified the master POM file (master/pom.xml) or have a maven network proxy issue. Neither of those are Sakai related but are in fact maven related.

Check out this for more tips: http://java.dzone.com/articles/mavens-non-resolvable-parent